# How to use private inheritance via constructing with arguments?

Tags: c++

Some code like this:

```
class maven
{
private:
        string username;
public:
        maven(string un)
        {
            username = un;
        }
};

class car : private maven
{
public:
       /... do something .../
};
```

Then I want a get a maven instance within the object car.
But how can I construct the maven object with argument?
I have looked up specification and annotation.

Comment: the requirements 'inheritance' and 'have an instance within' contradict each other. So which one do you want?

Comment: I want inheritance. Since private inheritance means instance with.

Comment: Inheritance means a `is a` kind of relationship, Composition means a `has a` kind of relationship, Pick one.

Comment: has a. I mean has a object with argument.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean how to construct the `maven` part of the `car` object, do this with an initialization list:

```
class car : private maven
{
public:
    // This way
    car() : maven("foo") {
    }

    // Or this way
    car(string username) : maven(username) {
    }
};
```

It's worth noting that this way you do not get a `maven` instance within `car`; actually, `car` itself is a `maven` deep inside (although it doesn't tell anyone about it).

Unless you need access to `maven`'s `protected` members for some reason, this way of doing things is not the best. You might want to consider *aggregating* an object of class `maven` instead, for example:

```
class car
{
private:
    maven m_maven;
public:
    // Initialize the member with a default parameter
    car() : m_maven("foo") {
    }

    // Or this way
    car(string username) : m_maven(username) {
    }
};
```

See [this page](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.3) of the C++ FAQ lite for a short discussion.

Comment: Another question, what if I do not want to instantiate an object, but use a static method instead?

Comment: In that way, is it like this: static static_method() : maven("foobar"){...}

Answer (score 2):

Create a constructor in `car` and initialise its base `maven` in the initialisation list.

```
class car : private maven
{
public:
    car(string un) : maven(un)
    {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class car : private maven
{
public:
    car() : maven("some_username")
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

See Jon's answer for the difference between private inheritance and composition, but if you want to access the `maven` instance because, say, there is a function like this:

```
void baz(maven*);
```

Then in both cases, only members and friends of `car` can access the `maven` instance, so given a member of `car` eg `car::zoo`:

In the case of private inheritance:

```
car::zoo(){ baz(this); }
```

or in the case of composition:

```
car::zoo(){ baz(&m_maven); }
```

In both cases no other functions nor methods outside `car`, nor methods in classes derived from `car` can do this.